# auto suggest data from grid to textboxes..in winforms

Tags: c#

Auto suggest data from grid to textboxes, in winforms.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = cn;
cmd.CommandText = "insert into studetail values('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + gen + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + clas + "','" + section + "')";
int n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), since it is unclear what you need help with.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This seems like just the tip of the iceberg. It's also worth mentioning that your query is not safe from sql injection. You should consider using parameters instead of concatenate unsanitized strings.